# add new elements XSLT

Tags: xslt

Have the following input xml which would like to transform to output XML

Input XML:

```
<O1>
    <A1>
        <C1>
            <CA1/>
        </C1>
    </A1>
    <A2>
        <C1>
            <C2>
                <CA2/>
            </C2>
        </C1>
    </A2>
</O1>


Output XML:
<O1>
    <A1>
        <C1>
            <CA1/>
            <status/>
        </C1>
        <status/>
    </A1>
    <A2>
        <C1>
            <C2>
                <CA2/>
                <status/>
            </C2>
            <status/>
        </C1>
        <status/>
    </A2>
</O1>
```

Input and Output structure are exactly same with exception of "status"
Have first done a copy of all nodes from input to output using

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Have difficulty in adding the status field under each of them now.
Have tried defining another template but didnt succeed

Goal is to add the status element under each "A" and "C"

Comment: Unless you explain your requirements to us, we can only guess at the logic of what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to add a `<status />` element after every element with a name starting in `C`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to add a `<status />` element after each element that starts with the letter `C`, simply add the following XSLT-1.0 template next to the *identity template*:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'C')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <status />
</xsl:template>
```

The output is as desired.

Comment: You could alternatively add a `name="Copy"` attribute to the identity template and then just have `<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'C')]">
  <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />
  <status />
</xsl:template>`